# How can I calculate the decimals of a number like this?

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods

I have a huge number like $(3\sqrt{5}+2)^{200}$ and I want to find the first 200 decimals.

Obviously I don't want to calculate the full number. I would rather an efficient numerical technique or a way to find a number with the same decimals and calculate that(I don't know if that's possible though).

Edit: I already have the number(different integer numbers than above but same structure), I have found that the first 114 decimals are 9's. Is there an analytical way to prove that the decimals are repeating 9's??

Comment: Welcome to Math Overflow! For numbers of this scale arbitrary precision floating point, e.g. Python's mpmath, should be quite enough. Alternatively, for a number $(a + b\sqrt{c})^d$ with $c$ squarefree, you can evaluate the number precisely in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{c}]$ as $N + M\sqrt{c}$, and then your problem reduces to finding a rounded value of $10^k M\sqrt{c}$ (here $k$ is chosen to given enough decimals), which can again be solved precisely e.g. by considering rational approximations to $\sqrt{c}$ via continued fractions.

Comment: One other trick is to find an approximating recurrence similar to Binet's formula. In OP example this would be $a_n = \frac{(2 + 3\sqrt{5})^n - (2 - 3\sqrt{5})^n}{6\sqrt{5}}$, which satisfies a recurrence, $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$, $a_{n + 2} = 4a_{n + 1} + 41a_n$. Then $(2 + 3\sqrt{5})^n = 6\sqrt{5}a_n + (2 - 3\sqrt{5})^n$. The second summand is quite a bit smaller, thus you'd have to evaluate it to smaller degree of precision.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov Thanks for your answers! Can you elaborate a bit on this part of your answer "Alternatively, for a number (a+bc√)d with c squarefree, you can evaluate the number precisely in Z[c√] as N+Mc√, and then your problem reduces to finding a rounded value of 10kMc√ (here k is chosen to given enough decimals), which can again be solved precisely e.g. by considering rational approximations to c√ via continued fractions.". 

I am not aware of the notation Z[c√]  and what it means. I also don't know how to do rational approximations of roots via continued fractions.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov Better if you can give me some references for these. Don't waste your time explaining.

Comment: As for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{c}]$, that just means working with expressions $a + b\sqrt{c}$ with $a, b$ integer. These can be added trivially, and multiplied by the rule $(a_1 + b_1\sqrt{c})(a_2 + b_2\sqrt{c}) = (a_1a_2 + cb_1b_2) + (a_1b_2 + a_2b_1)\sqrt{c}$. For continued fractions for roots see e.g. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Continued_fraction_expansion).

Comment: I note that as long as your question is purely practical, and limited to numbers up to, say, $1000$ digits, then just using arbitrary precision floats is certainly the way to go.

Comment: sage: K.<s> = QuadraticField(5); a = 2+3*s; b = a^200; b.n(digits=200) gives 9.6764976831156133048788279180888981089362814943255509483515512973624817479430815265095434364728183328771557274665385965131503467348008895311664220954809319985548215225847712076638014256020387899036957e187
I fear this not really a research-level question. It boils down to quick sqrt in R, which is well-known and powering in the quadratic field.

Comment: It is easy to fin the answer computationally. I am looking for something more algorithmic/analytical. Please check my edit.

Comment: When you know that the first 114 decimal digits are 9s you seem to think that the number is in fact just 1. That might be easier to prove than an argument that "finds all the digits". What you need to show is that your number is a power of the fundamental unit in that particular ring of algebraic integers. Lots known about that. Perhaps you should [edit] the question to ask about what you really want to know. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: "Is there an analytical way to prove that the decimals are repeating 9's??" the decimals are repeating nines then the number is rational and the repeating 9's can all be removed by adding one to the last non 9 digit.

Comment: Note that if you expand $(a\sqrt{d}+b)^n+(-a\sqrt{d}+b)^n$ using the binomial theorem, all the square roots drop out leaving you with an integer. So if it is the case that $|a\sqrt{d}−b|<1$ then the second term is almost zero, making $(a\sqrt{d}+b)^n$ is almost an integer. It can of course never actually be an integer assuming $d$ is not a square (because then $\sqrt{d}$ is irrational).

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, the easiest way for one single entry is to put your line into the WolframApha bar and then just click 3 or 4 times on the "More digits" button. It will take only a few seconds and then you can Copy-Paste the output into any program/file you wish: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283*sqrt%285%29%2B2%29%5E200

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple algorithm (coded in Python) to find upper and lower bounds on the square root of a number, in terms of the arbitrary-precision `Fraction` class.  It uses the native floating-point `sqrt` for its initial bounds, then the Secant Method to refine the guesss.

```
from math import sqrt
from fractions import Fraction

def sqrt_bounds(x, num_iterations):
    float_sqrt = sqrt(x)
    lo = Fraction(float_sqrt * 0.99999999)
    hi = Fraction(float_sqrt * 1.00000001)
    for _ in range(num_iterations):
        root = (x + lo * hi) / (lo + hi)
        if root ** 2 >= x:
            lo = root
        else:
            hi = root
    return (lo, hi)
```

Using 1000 iterations of this method, we can calculate $\sqrt{5}$ to within an absolute error of $5.6 \times 10^{-25}$.  From this, we can get upper and lower rational bounds on $(3\sqrt{5} + 2)^{200}$.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient approach to computing $\sqrt{5}$ to high precision is to note that it equals the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) $[2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ...]$.  Let $C_n$ = the approximation obtained by truncating the continued fraction after $n$ items (or $n-1$ fours).  It can be shown that if $n$ is odd, then $C_n < \sqrt{5}$, but if $n$ is even, then $C_n > \sqrt{5}$.

After 1000 iterations, we have a bounding interval $(C_{999}, C_{1000})$ with a width of only about $3.12 \times 10^{-1055}$.  This allows us to calculate $(3\sqrt{5} + 2)^{200}$ with an error bound of only $2.08 \times 10^{-1065}$.

> 96764976831156133048788279180888981089362814943255509483515512973624817479430815265095434364728183328771557274665385965131503467348008895311664220954809319985548215225847712076638014256020.38789903695741915809330554760738934834816306486204348469307273022035736139287476026617315281229418578469545871412842842059390792766703133903217811521510151363438942757128542112421403348679142448052041794058125135564346743321607936232834911287785681359009494042052297571388428025580973115978235547295923053480295837029330984400570513609725524271847567142218961571168005613065188931461118400102047475156980369237259783422502246934473622362190592291401895173200553225936949921393591443447641728468592541606123609978188468550467409799926644084550335067831622720866530905953806327417403693645974657499899865514627615355592343261877528002636234051289586777138538224447960826163991657482526651629312649314365511481511290306082704770968245626955271507691523742940444701787296463907201191347145670508393031850057708874799194275243507108980457537198208578576480804413262688671587837271751209522221439359698133526784567437585019950100445493216952190362739571004125722943941095898230561530807839177564006486569902289755322408384839325016586043339169088527952832759970139088690...

For additional digits, simply use more terms of the continued fraction.